# Stopping daemons from loading at boot time

Tags: boot, squid

I want to stop some daemons from loading at boot time, specially squid3. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: +1 perfectly phrased for someone searching for the answer to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [chkconfig](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chkconfig) utility for this purpose.

```
sudo apt-get install chkconfig
```

To check the run level status of squid you can run this command:

```
 chkconfig --list | grep squid
```

This will output something like below:

```
squid           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

To turn off squid in all run level you can  use this command:

```
sudo chkconfig  squid off

 chkconfig --list | grep squid

squid           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

To turn off squid in a particular run level you can use this command:

```
 chkconfig  --level 3  squid off
```

Comment: We have 7 leveles from (0 - 6).What are those levels?Can you explain us?

Comment: @karthik87:Here is a nice article about linux run levels. This will help you  : http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hlrunlevels.html

Comment: What about upstart scripts?

Answer (score 4):

The above answers did not work for my Ubuntu 16.04.

**Here is what it worked:**

```
sudo systemctl stop squid 
update-rc.d squid disable

sudo systemctl status squid
```

Although you may get an error like:

> insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script squid overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
>
> insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `squid' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
> insserv: fopen(.depend.stop): Permission denied

The service remains stopped even after reboot.

If you know why the error happens and how to fix it, please feel free to comment or edit the answer.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

System daemons can use either legacy SysV init scripts or the newer Upstart.

For sysv scripts there are several management tools, one of such tools is "sysv-rc-conf" from the "sysv-rc-conf" package, install it and launch it from the terminal.

Regarding Upstart as far as I know there is no management tool yet, you need to manually rename the corresponding script from /etc/init, eg:

```
mv /etc/init/ufw.conf /etc/init/ufw.conf.disabled
```

Squid3 uses sysv init scripts, you can disable it with sysv-rc-conf .

Comment: Addendum: When moving your upstart job away, you cannot manually start it anymore. It's probably better to just uncomment the "start on" part in the .conf file.

Answer (score 2):

Squid uses the old init system, so this command should do the trick: `sudo update-rc.d -f squid3 remove`.

For more find-grained control of when to start/stop the service: `sudo sysv-rc-conf`

Comment: Ad 1.: that will also remove the links to stop the service, which is probably not what you want in case you started it manually.

Comment: That's wrong, you can always start/stop it with `/etc/init.d/squid3 start` or `stop`.

Comment: It will remove the K*-links that stop the service _automatically_. ;)

Comment: Who would want that anyway? ;)

Comment: The lazy people (ME)! :-P

Answer (score 1):

Two the simplest ways (from my point of view).

1) `mv /etc/init/squid3.conf /etc/init/squid3.conf.disabled`

2) comment out the following line

```
start on runlevel [2345]
```

in `/etc/init/squid3.conf`

Comment: Number 2 was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks.